# XQuery regexp error

Tags: regex, xquery

Why next code returns true (Saxon-EE 9.2 for .NET)?

```
matches('some text>', '^[\w ]{3,200}$')
```

There is no > symbol in the pattern.
Thanks.

XQuery:

```
<regexp-test>
    <!-- why true? -->
    <test1>{matches('some text>', '^[\w ]{3,200}$')}</test1>
    <test2>{matches('some text>', '^[\w ]+$')}</test2>
    <test3>{matches('&lt; < >', '^[\w ]+$')}</test3>
    <!-- valid: --> 
    <test4>{matches('some text!', '^[\w ]+$')}</test4>  
    <test5>{matches('.,', '^[\w ]+$')}</test5> 
</regexp-test>
```

Output:

```
<regexp-test>
  <!-- why true? -->
  <test1>true</test1>
  <test2>true</test2>
  <test3>true</test3>
  <!-- valid: -->
  <test4>false</test4>
  <test5>false</test5>
</regexp-test>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code.  There's no way to tell what's wrong from the information you've given us.

Comment: What information? 
I have written a pattern, example text, XQuery compliler! What more?

Comment: This pattern definitely shouldn't match since `>` is not part of `\w`. So, as Alan Moore said, the problem probably is somewhere else - please post a complete code sample that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, experimentation and help from others in the eXist community, I find that the definition of character classes in UNICODE and used in the definition of regexps in XPath and XML schema is different to the POSIX classes.  In particular the characters

$+<=>^|~

are in the Symbol class \p{S} not the Punctuation class \p{P}. Since the definition of \w ( from http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes-with-errata.html ) is

"[#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}] (all characters except the set of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters) "

these characters will be included in \w

This leads to a workaround using [^\W\p{S}]

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a go...

I will guess that you meant to write

```
matches( 'some text' , '^[\w ]{3,200}$' )
```

The regex says to start at the beginning of the string (`^`), match at least 3, and at most 200 (`{3,200}`) characters or spaces (`[\w ]`), and then expect the end of the string (`$`).

So, `some text` will return true since it consists of the right characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]` and there are 9 of them.

If the match is this, for example

```
matches( 'some text' , '^[\w ]{3,5}$' )
```

The result should return false since it will only match strings of length 3 to 5.

Perhaps you think `\w` means whitespace or something else?

Comment: I think asker is wondering about the `>` present in the text but not in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I know regular expressions, and their bases, that you have described. But it was not a misprint, I meant it was a string with ">" (or other symbol, not a character: >, <,!, =, Etc.). The pattern does not have these characters, but nevertheless string "some text >" matches.
The same pattern works correctly in the implementation of regular expressions in .NET or Java. But in Saxon regexp something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is not a valid character in a string in this situation and needs to be replaced by its representation `&gt;`. I guess it is being silently dropped and therefore the regex matches.

See also [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_syntax.asp): "XQuery is case-sensitive and XQuery elements, attributes, and variables must be valid XML names." - and `>` is not allowed inside XML attributes.

Comment: I got same result when > replaced with &gt;. matches('&lt; < >', '^[\w ]+$') -- returns true.

Comment: What happens with `matches('&gt;', '^[\w ]+$')`?

Comment: Weird. Must be a bug in Saxon-EE or something.